# iOS 7 overrides CurrentContext modal presentation

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have a pretty standard view hierarchy, mainly with a `UITabBarController` containing several `UINavigationController`s.

I'm creating a new `UINavigationController` and presenting it modally from within one of the tabs.

I want it to show with `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`, so I'm setting it like so:

```
[newNavCon setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
```

And then, I present it like this:

```
[oldNavCon presentViewController:newNavCon animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But when it gets presented, it is full screen, not the current context that I set.

When I look at the breakpoints, the modal presentation style on `newNavCon` is changed to `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` immediately after `presentViewController`.

The thing that really confuses me is that this behavior happens *only* on iOS7. It works exactly as expected on iOS 8-10.

Why is this happening? Is there some specific quirk that I don't know about on iOS7? Why would the presentation style get overridden like this?

**EDIT**:
To clarify, here's the view hierarchy I'm working with:

- `UIViewController` (as a container, fullscreen)
- `UITabBarController` (not fullscreen, as controlled by the container)

  - `definesPresentationContext`
- `UINavigationController` (as tab root, presents the modal window)

  - `definesPresentationContext`
- `UINavigationController` (presented modally by the above `UIViewController`)

  - `modalPresentationStyle` = `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`
- `UIViewController`

Comment: I do use a custom subclass for my navCons, but when I change it to a standard UINavigationController, it still happens.

Comment: I added a symbolic breakpoint to see when it gets changed, and it's definitely not in code that I've written. The breakpoint stopped inside UIKit somewhere during the `presentViewController` operation. Unfortunately, I couldn't make any sense of it. I didn't see anything I could work with.

Comment: Thanks. That's as far as I had. It's just so strange that it doesn't want to present as current context. The documentation says it can, and as far as I can tell I'm doing everything correct. I figured my only hope was to see if anybody here at SO remembered some undocumented bug or quirk with iOS7's behavior.

And I'm not surprised you don't. I barely have one to test with, and it's annoying because I have to use XCode7 just to test with it...

Comment: Oh, one more thing. Even if I remove the modal navCon and just present the inner viewCon, it still gets changed to full screen. This is just super weird... It doesn't want to present anything to current context. Something has to be wrong with this. Either it's me or iOS7's UIKit can't handle this view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're testing on an iPhone device or simulator. In iOS 7 and before, `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` was an *iPad-only* feature.

Comment: Well, that would certainly explain why it keeps getting forced to full screen! And yeah I'm testing on an iPhone.

Comment: But to be perfectly clear, if something is presented modally in ios7 on an iPhone, then it can only be full screen?